# webserv permission for SFTP in PHPStorm

Tags: apache, permissions, sftp, phpstorm

On my webserver I use apache2 itk-mpm for vhost to run under on the own user. In desktop I want edit scripts using sFTP, but I obtain error permission denied for my ssh . If I have one local user e.g user and apache vhost are running as vhost1, vhost2 .... How i set permission to the vhost files if I want to be accesible in sftp for local user?

Comment: You should approach this by using the `umask` feature in your environment. It allows you to use the "group write permissions" for files.

Comment: Now I have permission for vhost files vhost1:vhost1. If I understand this i would make group web the user vhost1 and  user  would be members of these goup. And vhost files I set write permission for this group. Is it alright?

Comment: Yes, that is the right direction.